# Crystal Report 2011 vs Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Is there a difference between Crystal Reports 2011 and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010?

We are creating a number of ASP.Net applications and have been using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010. My boss recently purchased 5 licences for Crystal Reports 2011 thinking that we need them. After looking into it I don't believe we do anymore.

Would anyone be able to tell me which version I should be using? and what the difference between them is?

Edit: How is this not constructive? I'm asking what the difference is between the two products. One requires a licence the other doesn't. Theres not going to be an extended debate. Simple answer which I just can't find on google.

Note: If this should be moved to a different Stack Exchange website please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SAP Crystal Reports 2011: v14
- SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010: v13

Source: [Known Crystal Reports versions and service pack levels](http://www.softwareforces.com/FAQ/Known-Crystal-Reports-Versions-and-Service-Pack-Levels)

You'll have to investigate the features yourself and decide if they are useful or not.

Your biggest problems will be scalability and licensing--you may want to investigate [SAP Crystal Server](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sme/business-intelligence-crystal-solutions/sap-crystal-server/index.epx).